# How to solve this? The error is "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

Tags: vb.net

The code for Click event of Refresh button is below

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button50.Click
    WebBrowser.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: Somewhere you must declare a new instance of the web browser, you cannot use the static class.

Answer (score 0):

Non shared reference means the method or object you are calling is not exposed directly from its class. what you should do is to instantiate the class first.

```
Public obj As New CLASS_NAME
obj.WebBrowser.Refresh()
```

Something like this should do or if you created the WebBrowser.Refresh() method, you can add the shared modifier to it

```
Public Shared Sub Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: His problem is that he has not instantiated the web browser itself. He did not create it or a custom class. It's the normal WebBrowser component that you can use in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

As @Visual Vincent mentioned in a comment, you need to instantiate the object you are trying to work with;

```
Dim newWebBroswer = new WebBrowser
newWebBroswer.Url = 'Set the URL
newWebBroswer.Refresh()
```

MSDN link for some help on WebBrowser: [MSDN-Web Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx)